# How to get around :app:validateSigningDebug?

Tags: android, signed-apk

I took a opensource android project from github and wanted to work on it.
When ever I try to run the app, I get the following error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.
> Keystore file C:\Users\aditya\Krishna\prms-android-aananthcn-master\prms-android-master\app\Users\aananth\AndroidStudioProjects\.license\dummy.jks not found for signing config 'config'.
```

I do not have the dummy.jks file.
How can i get around this error and run the app?

Comment: post your gradle code

Answer (score 0):

Go to gradle app file and remove or comment the line which says :app:validateSigningDebug